# Let$\ n$ be an odd abundant number. What is the best upper bound to $\ \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$?

Tags: number-theory

**NOTE**: **Of course the bound of the product of primes below is incorrect. I knew very little of this stuff and it seems was too lazy and gaga** (I still am gaga) **to check that W|A was acting stupid.**

In order to obtain my upper bound I use and extend a method I learnt from Greg Martin, who answered another question of mine.

**Lemma**: Let $i>1$ be an integer, and let $p$ be the largest prime dividing $i$. Then,
$$
\frac{\sigma(i)}i \le \bigg(1+\frac1p\bigg) \frac{\sigma(i/p)}{i/p}.
$$

**Proof**: Write $i=p^rm$ where $p\nmid m$. Then,
$$
\frac{\sigma(i)/i}{\sigma(i/p)/(i/p)} = \frac{\sigma(p^rm)}{p\sigma(p^{r-1}m)} = \frac{\sigma(p^r)\sigma(m)}{p\sigma(p^{r-1})\sigma(m)} = \frac{\sigma(p^r)}{p\sigma(p^{r-1})}.
$$
Since $\sigma(p^r) = \frac{p^{r+1}-1}{p-1}$, this gives
$$
\frac{\sigma(i)/i}{\sigma(i/p)/(i/p)} = \frac{p^{r+1}-1}{p(p^r-1)} \le \frac{p+1}p = 1+\frac1p.
$$
[Dickson proved](https://archive.org/stream/jstor-2370405/2370405#page/n5/mode/2up) there are no odd abundant numbers with less than three prime factors, hence, if$\ P $ is the largest prime dividing$\ n$, we have$\ P\ge7$. So, let$\ n=k\times PA$, where$\ PA$ is *any* odd primitive abundant number and$\ k$ is an odd integer of the form$\ 3^a 5^b 7^c 11^d...$, where obviously all the exponents are non-negative. We shall use$\ 945$ as$\ PA$ simply because it is the first odd (and primitive) abundant number, but we'll show hereinafter that any$\ PA$ would do fine. Thus, we have $$\ \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}\le \frac{8}{7} \frac{\sigma\left(\frac{945k}{7}\right)}{\frac{945k}{7}}.$$ For a start, suppose that in the above factorization of$\ k$, the only positive exponent is$\ a$. Hence,$$\ \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}\le \frac{8}{7} \frac{\sigma\left(5\times 3^{a+3}\right)}{5\times 3^{a+3}}=\frac{8\times 6\left(3^{a+4}-1\right)}{7\times 5\times 2\times 3^{a+3}}<\frac{72}{35}.$$ If only$\ a$ and$\ b$ are positive, $$\ \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}\le \frac{8}{7} \frac{\sigma\left(3^{a+3}5^{b+1}\right)}{3^{a+3}5^{b+1}}=\frac{8\left(3^{a+4}-1\right)\left(5^{b+2}-1\right)}{7\times 2\times 4\times 3^{a+3}5^{b+1}}<\frac{15}{7}.$$ If only$\ a, b$ and$\ c$ are positive, $$\ \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}\le \frac{8}{7} \frac{\sigma\left(3^{a+3}5^{b+1}7^c\right)}{3^{a+3}5^{b+1}7^c}=\frac{8\left(3^{a+4}-1\right)\left(5^{b+2}-1\right)\left(7^{c+1}-1\right)}{2\times 4\times 6\times 3^{a+3}5^{b+1}7^{c+1}}<\frac{5}{2}.$$ Having reached$\ P$, it is easy to see that from now on as the factorization gets larger by$\ p_n^\alpha$, we just multiply the last ratio by $\ \frac{\left(p_n^{\alpha+1}-1\right)}{p_n^\alpha(p_n-1)}<\frac{p_n}{p_n-1}$, leaving out, aside$\ 2$, only$\ 7$, and this is true for *any* $\ PA$. 
As a consequence, $$\ \frac{\sigma\left(\frac{n}{7}\right)}{\frac{n}{7}}<\prod_{j=2}^\infty \frac{p_j}{p_j-1}<\frac{11.0454}{2}=5.5227.$$(if it necessary, for the last result see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*+3%2F2+*+5%2F4+*+7%2F6+*+... and click on >More terms in the approximation section)  Therefore, we can conclude $$\ \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}<\frac{8}{7} 5.5227=6.3116\overline {571428}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ummm...$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ is unbounded above for odd  $n$.

Lemma: For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\sum_{d\mid n} \frac{1}{d}$.

Proof: Let $d_1<d_2<\dots<d_t$ be the divisors of $n$. Then $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\frac{d_1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{d_t}{n}=\frac{1}{d_t}+\cdots+\frac{1}{d_1}$.  QED.

Now if we choose an odd $n$ that is divisible by $3, 5, 7, \dots, 2k+1$, then $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}\ge \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac17+\cdots+\frac{1}{2k+1}$.  This is a partial sum of the odd harmonic series, which is divergent.  So by choosing $k$ large enough, we can make $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ as large as we please.

Comment: Using the mertens theorem, one can even prove $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup\frac{\sigma(n)}{n\log\log n}=e^\gamma$$

Comment: @karvens Does that lim sup hold if restricted to odd $n$?

Comment: No but I think a similar result holds. For odd $n$,$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup \frac{\sigma(n)}{n\log\log n}=\frac{e^\gamma}{2}$$ Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Alright, I see, I also checked. What is my mistake?

Comment: @Numberlover--I think the mistake is that in fact $\prod_2^\infty \frac{p_j}{p_j-1}$ is divergent to $\infty$.  You have it bounded above by $5.5227$.

Comment: Looking again at this question makes me blush, ahah! I hate it when W|A acts stupid, luckily now I don't trust it so much anymore (and, I'm not anymore too lazy to check, my God lol). Thanks for your answer! paw and @karvens: In fact, denoting with CA the set of colossally abundant numbers, we have $$\lim_{\begin{smallmatrix} n\to\infty\cr n\in CA \end{smallmatrix}}  \frac{\sigma(n)}{n\log\log n}=e^{\gamma}$$
Can any of you confirm that if n is superabundant we still don't have equality between lim sup and lim inf?

Comment: *too lazy and gaga

Comment: paw, you don't know?

Comment: I don't know.  Sorry.

Comment: paw, I see that my links were deleted when I had to improve the formatting. Here one can learn about [colossally abundant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ColossallyAbundantNumber.html) and [superabundant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SuperabundantNumber.html) numbers, but I guess that doesn't help you so much. Perhaps @karvens can confirm.

Answer (score 1):

just did this, seems the same idea as the other answer, I would not expect there to be an upper bound. Let $n$ be the least common multiple of the **odd** numbers from $1$ to $4079.$ Then $\sigma(n) / n > e^2 \approx 7.389.$ Taking the LCM is the easiest way to get fairly large values of $\sigma$ or the number of divisors. Note that the exponent of some prime $p$ is roughly proportional to $1/\log p$

```
4063    1.999728858605067
4065    1.999728858605067
4067    1.999728858605067
4069    1.999728858605067
4071    1.999728858605067
4073    1.999974347743319
4075    1.999974347743319
4077    1.999974347743319
4079    2.000219475824451
4081    2.000219475824451
4083    2.000219475824451
4085    2.000219475824451
4087    2.000219475824451
4089    2.000219475824451
4091    2.000463884966393
4093    2.000708174695319
4095    2.000708174695319
4097    2.000708174695319
4099    2.000952106883233
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```